# Как такое сверстать на чистом css?

Tags: html, css

Мне нужно сверстать что-то подобное, но ума не могу приложить, как это сделать. Помогите, пожалуйста.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Svg, border-image, а вообще - сложно...

Comment: делается две строки, 4 колонки через flex, с распределением ширины, на задний фон картинки. Что сложного? Что именно не понятно?

Comment: @SergeyGlazirin, ну вообще-то я вопрос понял, что как раз картинки сверстать надо, а не лейаут. Лейаут-то действительно легко верстается. Кстати, через grid делается намного лучше, чем через flex.

Comment: Если вам не сложно, то покажите оба примера, пожалуйста. И как сделать input одинаковой ширины с кнопкой, если использовать один из методов?

Comment: @JessieRutherford так у Вас сложность с макетом или стилизацией уточните пожалуйста пока всех не запутали)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ну если вас интересует только расположение, то как вариант использовать [Grid Layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Grid_Layout).

```css
.grid { 
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr) 2.5fr;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 400px;
}

.grid input {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <input type="button" value="8">
  <input type="button" value="30">
  <input type="button" value="50">
  <input type="number" value="0" min="0" max="2000">
  <input type="button" value="200">
  <input type="button" value="500">
  <input type="button" value="2000">
  <input type="submit" value="BUTTON">
</div>
```

Если же речь про стилизацию, то так же как и в старые добрые - [background](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background)